# Python - Quality of inset image in figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to include an inset image (ellipsoid) on to a plot using `imshow` and save the plot in the Python script. Following is the actual code used to add the inset image in the plotting script:

```
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import  matplotlib.image as mpimg
import  numpy as np

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(9, 4), constrained_layout=True)
X = range(10)
ax1.plot(X, [x*x for x in X])
ax2.plot(X, [x*x for x in X])
insetfig= mpimg.imread('inset.eps')
newax = fig.add_axes([0.095, 0.673, 0.22, 0.22], anchor='NW', zorder=0, transform=ax1.transAxes)
newax.imshow(insetfig)
newax.axis('off')
# plt.savefig('figure.eps')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The issue is that, upon saving the plot as `eps` (or any other format), I notice that there is severe loss in image quality of the inset. Left side plot is what I achieved by having the inset placed in the python script. I used the same inset figure (ellipsoid) and directly added it in the latex file in the right subfigure. As you can see, there is better quality on the right one. However, I do not prefer to include the inset via Latex. I want to permanently have the inset added from the Python. How to improve the image quality of the inset in Python?

Comment: You could try to increase the dpi when creating the figure, or when saving it.  The code shown in your question is skipping most steps that influence the image quality.  Also note that `imshow()` has a parameter `interpolation=` with which you could experiment (e.g. `imshow(..., interpolation='lanczos')`, but this is much less important than the dpi.

Comment: Updated with a proper MWE. It is simpler and more to the point now.

Comment: @JohanC I could not control `dpi` yet since I generated the shiny ellipsoid with Octave. I had to take a screenshot due to the issues with saving figure. That is a separate SO question now unfortunately.

Comment: You control dpi when you save the figure.  The dpi on your screen is by default 100 or 200, but you can also change that to suit if you like

Comment: Okay. Even the saved plot in `png` format with inset looked better. Only the `eps` version had this poor resolution issue. Increasing `dpi` in the final save solved the issue: `plt.savefig('figure.eps', dpi=300)`

Answer (score 0):

Even the saved plot in `png` format with inset looked better. Only the `eps` version had this poor resolution issue. Increasing `dpi` in the final save solved the issue:

`plt.savefig('figure.eps', dpi=300)`

Resulting improvement (in left figure):
[image]

PS: If you cannot really see the inset image quality difference, open the Q&A figures in separate tab, you will see the difference clearly.